# WSDL security policy ignored with Apache CXF client

Tags: cxf

I'm trying to call a web service where the WSDL contains a policy to sign and encrypt request and response. I'm using Apache CXF with client defined as below within a spring context file. Apache CXF (2.6.6) seems to ignore the security policy in the WSDL and doesn't sign/encrypt the request. I have the full bundle CXF which should include the security modules. Any ideas?

```
<jaxws:client id="commercialStatusClient" 
              name="{http://tempuri.org/}CommercialStatus"
              serviceClass="blah.client.status.ICommercialStatus"
              address="http://blah.co.uk/CommercialStatus.svc" 
              depends-on="keystoreProperties"
              wsdlLocation="http://blah.co.uk/CommercialStatus.svc?wsdl">              
  <jaxws:properties>
    <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value-ref="keystoreProperties"/>
    <entry key="ws-security.signature.username" value="clientalias"/>
    <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value-ref="keystoreProperties"/>
    <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="serveralias"/>
    <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value-ref="keystorePasswordCallback"/>      
  </jaxws:properties>    
</jaxws:client>
```